# org-mode table: how to add the left-most vertical line with column groups notation?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

The [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-Groups.html#Column-groups) suggests that column groups syntax is a *general* way to add vertical lines in a table.

For instance, the following `org-mode`'s table snippet

```
|--------+----------|
|        | Column 1 |
|--------+----------|
| /      | <>       |
| Line 1 |          |
|--------+----------|
```

is rendered in pdf as

[image]

and in ASCII as

```
--------+----------+
        | Column 1 |
--------+----------+
 Line 1 |          |
--------+----------+
```

(Apparently, this doesn't work for HTML as the boundaries are controlled by CSS).

My question is: how to use [column groups](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-Groups.html#Column-groups) to obtain the left-most vertical line?

The idea is to use **one syntax** to export the table with specific vertical lines in different formats.

I'm aware of the alternative way to achieve it using `#+ATTR_LaTeX: :align |c|c|`, but it's specific to LaTeX.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it with column groups. What's wrong with the `#+attr_latex` approach?

Comment: @NickD I edited the question (in brief, `#+attr_latex` is not only cumbersome but also specific to LaTeX) and found the answer in passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901384/8274517) suggests adding one extra column to achieve what is required, i.e.

```
|---+--------+----------|
|   |        | Column 1 |
|---+--------+----------|
| / | <      | <>       |
|   | Line 1 |          |
|---+--------+----------|
```

Comment: This very example does not not work with org 9.6.11. The leftmost and rightmost vertical lines are missing in html export (they are present in ascii and latex export, though).